# Changing colour of icons on scroll in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, scroll, clip

I am working on a project that has social media icons fixed to the side of the window. They change colour as the page scrolls and encounters divs with a class of either 'black' or 'white.' It is a smooth scroll. And icons can be half of the colour as shown in this image:

[image]

Currently we have it working using CSS clip masking in all modern browsers. However, we have found late in the game that clipping is not supported in IE/Edge.

Is there a way to achieve a similar effect in IE?

Comment: Use two icons: one white and one black, show only part of it

Comment: That is basically what we are doing with the clipping. Is there another way to do it without?